# Scala: How to check the type of Array[T]

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching

I have a `Array[T]`, how to check the type of it?

I tried

```
def check[T](a: Array[T]) = {
  a match {
    case _: Array[Int] => // create type specified IntVector
    case _: Array[Float] => // create type specified FloatVector
  }
}
```

the compiler raise error

```
Scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type, found: Array[Int], required: Array[T]
```

---

The reason I want to do this is, suppose I am able to enumerate all the types, and currently there is only Int and Float

```
def check[T](a: Array[T]) = {
  val base: Base = baseVector
  val derived = a match {
    case _: Array[Int] => base.asInstanceOf[IntVector]      
    case _: Array[Float] => base.asInstanceOf[FloatVector]
  }
  derived.run()
}
abstract class Base
  def run()
class IntVector extends Base
  override def run()
class FloatVector extends Base
  override def run()
```

Comment: What version of Scala do you use?

Comment: @texasbruce 2.11.11

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez As in question mentioned, I need to create different objects in terms of different `Array[T]`

Comment: I can’t reproduce for any version > 2.11: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/TH0w7GuvTCqOFewA2TrNEA

Comment: @texasbruce I found the code works in your online editor, but the error is raised in IntelliJ IDEA...

Comment: Trust the compiler, not the IDE

Comment: @Litchy what would be the return type of the function? **Any**? That also doesn't feel useful. I am asking about the meta-problem. Do you know the type of the array on all the places you are calling this or is the type determined in the runtime?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I have updated the question to clarify my purpose.

Comment: @Litchy you probably would be better using a [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a cheap-trick that may work for you:

```
  def check[T](a: Array[T]) = {
    a.headOption match {
      case Some(_:Int) => "Int"
      case Some(_:Float) => "Float"
      case None => "None"
    }
  }
```

This is without using any reflection. With compile-time reflection:

```
def check2[T: ClassTag](a: Array[T]) = {
    import scala.reflect._
    val e = implicitly[ClassTag[T]]
    e match {
      case x if x == classTag[Int] => "Int"
      case y if y == classTag[Float] => "Float"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
def check[T](a: Array[T]) = {
  a match {
    case x if x.isInstanceOf[Array[Int]] => println("int")
    case y if y.isInstanceOf[Array[Float]]  => println("float")
    case _ => println("some other type")
  }
}
```